# get object details of observables with angularfire2 in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

in an ionic2 project with angularfire2 + firebase I am trying to transform the data out of the firebase table into something usable in the .ts file.

**that works:**

in .ts

```
this.list = af.database.list('/items');
```

in html

```
*ngFor="let item of list | async"
```

This give me all objects to use with {{item.val}}
However, I want to use this data directly in the script instead of viewing so I am trying to access it by variables with subscribe in typescript. this is the current approach and

**that doesnt work:**

```
this.af.database.list('/items/', { preserveSnapshot: true } )
  .subscribe(snapshots => 
  {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => 
    {
      if ( !someList.some(x=>x==snapshot.key) ) 
      {
          someList.push(snapshot.key);
          console.log(snapshot.val());

          this.af.database.object('/items/'+snapshot.key, { preserveSnapshot: true } ) 
          .subscribe( item => 
          {
            console.log(item.val();
          });
      }

    })
  });
```

It logs [object Object] for each item in the console.

I dont get how I get to the content of either [object Object] returned by the observables without touching html, best case as easy as item.value?

I found some examples with .map which returns for me *TypeError: item.map is not a function.*

How to get to the content of those objects?

Any help or hints to test are appreciated
Thank you

Comment: If you are not binding the data to the UI, I'd recommend simply accessing it with the bare Firebase JavaScript SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Answer (score 0):

actually using map works for me now; it has to be cast on the list and not the object.